# How to execute a file via adb command line?

Tags: rooting, adb, command-line

I am trying to root my Motorola Xoom. Root checker pro currently tells me that "Executing this file can grant root access!" So I want to try that.

the file is located in `system/bin` and is called `su`.

I have gotten this far:

`adb shell`

`cd system/bin`

**How do I execute the `system/bin/su` file via the adb command line?**

Comment: have you tried simply to type `su`, followed by the Enter-key? Sounds pretty stupid, maybe, but that's how `su` works. No cd'ing, it's even in the `$PATH`.

Comment: I tried that and nothing happened... I'll say `adb shell` `cd system/bin` and once it says `root@android:/system/bin # ` I type `su` and hit enter. then the following line will say "su" and that's about it, i'm back at my previous prompt `root@android:/system/bin # ` ?

Comment: If the prompt character is a `#` instead of a `$` then the shell already has root access. The `root` at the start should have been a bit of a clue.

Comment: Hm... Root Checker says "Root Access is not properly configured or was not granted". And both apps that I would like to use which require root (basically the only reason why I am trying to root) also don't work, saying I dont have root O_o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few suggestions (this is a shell so I'm guessing you have basic shell commands) one or all of these may work:

First try: sh su

Then: bash su

Then: ./su

If it has an extension give all the above commands a try with the extension of su

Also as a suggestion to see what commands are available just type: help

[EDIT]

since you mentioned not having root access try using the sudo command before su (and the above commands if needed)